# Create an api using lumen and neo4j

Tags: rest, neo4j, lumen, neoeloquent, fastroute

I want to create an api rest using [lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com/) that it will comunicate with neo4j, for this purpose I'm using [NeoEloquent](https://github.com/Vinelab/NeoEloquent).
I've already read the NeoEloquent's documentation but I'm confused. I've understand how lumen it work with a relational database, there is a model, a controller, every action that I want to do on my db pass through a routes that specify the method to use, but I don't understand how this work with a graph database.
In particular I don't understand how can I create new label, retrieve all label and relationship using the Http methods.
I've try to follow the same procedure that it's explain in this [guide](https://auth0.com/blog/developing-restful-apis-with-lumen/) (clearly readapting it to my use case) but without success.

### Example

Let we say that we have two labels with a many to many relationship, this labels will be Exhibit and Zone. We want to retrieve the zone that is associate to the Exhibit that has a specific identificator.
So, the query will be something like this:

```
MATCH (e:Exhibit)-[belongs_to]->(z:Zone) WHERE e.exhibit_id = {exhibit_id} RETURN z
```

For do this query we need to have this routes that it has to present in *web.php* file:

```
$router->get('/', function () use ($router) {
    return $router->app->version();
});

$router->group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () use ($router) {

    $router->get('exhibit',  ['uses' => 'ExhibitController@showAllExhibit']);

    $router->get('exhibit/{exhibit_id}', ['uses' => 'ExhibitController@retrieveZone']);
  });
```

With this routes we are saying:
when come a request with a *get* method, go inside the *ExhibitController* class and call the *retrieveZone* function.
This is what is present in controller class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Exhibit;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ExhibitController extends Controller
{

    public function showAllExhibit()
    {
        return response()->json(Exhibit::all());
    }

    public function showOneExhibit($id)
    {
        return response()->json(Exhibit::find($id));
    }

    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $exhibit = Exhibit::create($request->all());

        return response()->json($exhibit, 201);
    }

    public function update($id, Request $request)
    {
        $exhibit = Exhibit::findOrFail($id);
        $exhibit->update($request->all());

        return response()->json($exhibit, 200);
    }

    public function delete($id)
    {
        Exhibit::findOrFail($id)->delete();
        return response('Deleted Successfully', 200);
    }

    public function retrieveZone($exhibit_id)
    {
        $result = Exhibit::findZone($exhibit_id);
        return response()->json($result,201);
    }
}
```

When we call *retrieveZone* function, we will call the function *findZone* as well that is present in Exhibit model:

```
<?php

    namespace App;

    use Vinelab\NeoEloquent\Eloquent\Model;
    use Vinelab\NeoEloquent\Facade\Neo4jSchema;

    class Exhibit extends Model{
        protected $label = 'Exhibit';

        protected $fillable = [];

        protected $hidden = [];

        public function belongsToManyZone(){
            return $this->belongsToMany('Zone', 'belongs_to');
        }

        public static function findZone($exhibit_id){
            $exhibit = Exhibit::find($exhibit_id);

            return $exhibit->belongsToManyZone();
        }
    }
```

The *Zone* class:

```
<?php

    namespace App;

    use Vinelab\NeoEloquent\Eloquent\Edges\EdgeIn;
    use Vinelab\NeoEloquent\Eloquent\Model;

    class Zone extends Model{
        protected $label = 'Zone';

        protected $fillable = ['name'];

        protected $hidden = [];
    }
```

This is what I've done for translate the query using NeoEloquent, Lumen and Fastroute, but the result is *500 Internal Server Error*.

**Stack Trace**

```
 [2018-10-11 16:37:18] local.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Class 'Zone' not found in E:\laravel-projects\api_certose\vendor\vinelab\neoeloquent\src\Eloquent\Model.php:291
Stack trace:
#0 E:\laravel-projects\api_certose\app\Exhibit.php(16): Vinelab\NeoEloquent\Eloquent\Model->belongsToMany('Zone', 'BELONGS_TO')
#1 E:\laravel-projects\api_certose\app\Exhibit.php(22): App\Exhibit->zones()
#2 E:\laravel-projects\api_certose\app\Http\Controllers\ExhibitController.php(44): App\Exhibit::findZone('159')
#3 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\ExhibitController->retrieveZone('159')
#4 E:\laravel-projects\api_certose\vendor\illuminate\container\BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 E:\laravel-projects\api_certose\vendor\illuminate\container\BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#6 E:\laravel-projects\api_certose\vendor\illuminate\container\BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Laravel\Lumen\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#7 E:\laravel-projects\api_certose\vendor\illuminate\container\Container.php(564): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Laravel\Lumen\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#8 E:\laravel-projects\api_certose\vendor\laravel\lumen-framework\src\Concerns\RoutesRequests.php(373): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array, Array)
#9 E:\laravel-projects\api_certose\vendor\laravel\lumen-framework\src\Concerns\RoutesRequests.php(339): Laravel\Lumen\Application->callControllerCallable(Array, Array)
#10 E:\laravel-projects\api_certose\vendor\laravel\lumen-framework\src\Concerns\RoutesRequests.php(313): Laravel\Lumen\Application->callLumenController(Object(App\Http\Controllers\ExhibitController), 'retrieveZone', Array)
#11 E:\laravel-projects\api_certose\vendor\laravel\lumen-framework\src\Concerns\RoutesRequests.php(275): Laravel\Lumen\Application->callControllerAction(Array)
#12 E:\laravel-projects\api_certose\vendor\laravel\lumen-framework\src\Concerns\RoutesRequests.php(260): Laravel\Lumen\Application->callActionOnArrayBasedRoute(Array)
#13 E:\laravel-projects\api_certose\vendor\laravel\lumen-framework\src\Concerns\RoutesRequests.php(230): Laravel\Lumen\Application->handleFoundRoute(Array)
#14 E:\laravel-projects\api_certose\vendor\laravel\lumen-framework\src\Concerns\RoutesRequests.php(164): Laravel\Lumen\Application->handleDispatcherResponse(Array)
#15 E:\laravel-projects\api_certose\vendor\laravel\lumen-framework\src\Concerns\RoutesRequests.php(413): Laravel\Lumen\Application->Laravel\Lumen\Concerns\{closure}()
#16 E:\laravel-projects\api_certose\vendor\laravel\lumen-framework\src\Concerns\RoutesRequests.php(166): Laravel\Lumen\Application->sendThroughPipeline(Array, Object(Closure))
#17 E:\laravel-projects\api_certose\vendor\laravel\lumen-framework\src\Concerns\RoutesRequests.php(107): Laravel\Lumen\Application->dispatch(NULL)
#18 E:\laravel-projects\api_certose\public\index.php(28): Laravel\Lumen\Application->run()
#19 {main} {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Class 'Zone' not found at E:\\laravel-projects\\api_certose\\vendor\\vinelab\
eoeloquent\\src\\Eloquent\\Model.php:291)
[stacktrace]
#0 E:\\laravel-projects\\api_certose\\app\\Exhibit.php(16): Vinelab\\NeoEloquent\\Eloquent\\Model->belongsToMany('Zone', 'BELONGS_TO')
#1 E:\\laravel-projects\\api_certose\\app\\Exhibit.php(22): App\\Exhibit->zones()
#2 E:\\laravel-projects\\api_certose\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\ExhibitController.php(44): App\\Exhibit::findZone('159')
#3 [internal function]: App\\Http\\Controllers\\ExhibitController->retrieveZone('159')
#4 E:\\laravel-projects\\api_certose\\vendor\\illuminate\\container\\BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 E:\\laravel-projects\\api_certose\\vendor\\illuminate\\container\\BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#6 E:\\laravel-projects\\api_certose\\vendor\\illuminate\\container\\BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Laravel\\Lumen\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#7 E:\\laravel-projects\\api_certose\\vendor\\illuminate\\container\\Container.php(564): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Laravel\\Lumen\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#8 E:\\laravel-projects\\api_certose\\vendor\\laravel\\lumen-framework\\src\\Concerns\\RoutesRequests.php(373): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array, Array)
#9 E:\\laravel-projects\\api_certose\\vendor\\laravel\\lumen-framework\\src\\Concerns\\RoutesRequests.php(339): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->callControllerCallable(Array, Array)
#10 E:\\laravel-projects\\api_certose\\vendor\\laravel\\lumen-framework\\src\\Concerns\\RoutesRequests.php(313): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->callLumenController(Object(App\\Http\\Controllers\\ExhibitController), 'retrieveZone', Array)
#11 E:\\laravel-projects\\api_certose\\vendor\\laravel\\lumen-framework\\src\\Concerns\\RoutesRequests.php(275): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->callControllerAction(Array)
#12 E:\\laravel-projects\\api_certose\\vendor\\laravel\\lumen-framework\\src\\Concerns\\RoutesRequests.php(260): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->callActionOnArrayBasedRoute(Array)
#13 E:\\laravel-projects\\api_certose\\vendor\\laravel\\lumen-framework\\src\\Concerns\\RoutesRequests.php(230): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->handleFoundRoute(Array)
#14 E:\\laravel-projects\\api_certose\\vendor\\laravel\\lumen-framework\\src\\Concerns\\RoutesRequests.php(164): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->handleDispatcherResponse(Array)
#15 E:\\laravel-projects\\api_certose\\vendor\\laravel\\lumen-framework\\src\\Concerns\\RoutesRequests.php(413): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->Laravel\\Lumen\\Concerns\\{closure}()
#16 E:\\laravel-projects\\api_certose\\vendor\\laravel\\lumen-framework\\src\\Concerns\\RoutesRequests.php(166): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->sendThroughPipeline(Array, Object(Closure))
#17 E:\\laravel-projects\\api_certose\\vendor\\laravel\\lumen-framework\\src\\Concerns\\RoutesRequests.php(107): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->dispatch(NULL)
#18 E:\\laravel-projects\\api_certose\\public\\index.php(28): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->run()
#19 {main}
"}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on which parts did not result in the expected behavior you wanted with code examples? Your questions is very generic and therefore hard to answer. Please explaind what you have tried, what didn't work about that and what you expect as output.

Comment: I have edited my answer and I have add an example

Comment: What does the lumen.log file (in `storage/logs`) say? The internal server error should be more clearly logged there

Comment: Essentially class Zone not found

Comment: That looks fine, could you provide the whole error + stacktrace for this issue? I am trying to reproduce the issue to help you further (by comparing it with my own working neo4j + lumen project) and I need as much context as possible, sorry to ask for so much extra information ;)

Comment: sure, don't worry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for NeoEloquent to make the connection between your models you also need to define the 'related' model, with the line `$this->belongsToMany('Zone', 'belongs_to');` specifies that this class is related to another class (i.e. a node in the graph database) and connected with a relation.

In order to fix your problem you will need to specify this class with at least the following:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Vinelab\NeoEloquent\Eloquent\Model;
use Vinelab\NeoEloquent\Facade\Neo4jSchema;

class Zone extends Model{}
```

Also I would recommend renaming `belongsToManyZone()` to `zones()` to improve the readability of the code, because then you can do the following to get all `Zones` of an `Exhibit`:

```
$result = Exhibit::findZone($exhibit_id);
$zones = $result->zones
```

Otherwise it would have been `$result->belongsToManyZone` which reads a bit weird.

Also try to change `$this->belongsToMany('App\Zone', 'belongs_to');` as this will ensure the right namespace and class will be used and can be found.

I hope this resolves your issue

Comment: I appreciate your solution, but the class Zone it's already present

Comment: Could you also add this class in your question? (Or at least provide the namespace where it resides?)

Comment: I've added the zone class

Comment: I have added more information to my answer, I hope this resolves your issue @M.Morris

Comment: You're welcome! Good luck :) if you have any more issues with neo4j in combination with lumen feel free to send me a chat message as I am working on a similair project and already encountered a lot of issues myself so i might be able to help :)